# Add function to game on "True or False" on pure js

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am making a on js "True or False" game. Assertion titles appear on the screen one by one. The user responds to each statement in turn. There are 5 statements in total. - If the user clicked on the False button then the following statement appears. And if it's true then a description appears. You can go to the next question by clicking on the white circle under the headings, which turns into red if an answer has already been given to it (any) or by clicking on further.

What is the best way to make the questions change without reloading the page and make the navigation circles are active in pure js? The available code and an approximate view of the functionality are below:

```html
<h1>statement 1</h1>
<div id="text" style="display:none;">Text of statement</div>
<button onclick="chpok('text')"><h2 onclick="chpok('arrow')">True</h2></button>
<button onclick="chpok('arrow')"><h2>False</h2></button>
<h2 id="arrow" onclick="chpok('block1')" style="display:none;">Next</h2>

<div class="block1" id="block1" style="display: none;">
  <h1>statement 2</h1>
  <div id="text2" style="display:none;">Text of statement</div>
  <button onclick="chpok('text2')"><h2 onclick="chpok('arrow2')">True</h2></button>
  <button onclick="chpok('arrow2')"><h2>False</h2></button>
  <h2 id="arrow2" onclick="chpok('block2')" style="display:none;">Next</h2>
</div>

<div class="block2" id="block2" style="display: none;">
  <h1>statement 3</h1>
  <div id="text3" style="display:none;">Text of statement</div>
  <button onclick="chpok('text3')"><h2 onclick="chpok('arrow3')">True</h2></button>
  <button onclick="chpok('arrow3')"><h2>False</h2></button>
  <h2 id="arrow3" style="display:none;">Next</h2>
</div>

<script>function chpok(id) {
  elem=document.getElementById(id);
  state=elem.style.display;
  if (state=='none') elem.style.display='';
}</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very broad question, but I'm gonna try and answer it by breaking it down a bit.
There's actually three issues in this question.

1. How do i display information from JS in the DOM?
2. How can i act on a button press to update this information?
3. How can we track which questions was answered?

Let's start with issue #1: For a task like this it helps making the question structure in JavaScript or JSON first. Every question has 4 pieces of information: `statement`, `description`, `correctAnswer`, `answer`.
We also need to create a function that handles assigning the values into the DOM. In this example we will call it `selectTask(id)` we're gonna run this on launch.

For Issue #2 we can reuse the `selectTask(id)` function to display the next answer, but we should add another function called `answer(value)` which takes what you've answered as an argument, this function sets the `answer` field of your statement object and calls selectTask for the next task. To run JS function you can use "onclick".

Finally, for issue #3, we have to apply some styling to the overview buttons to indicate which are correct or false, and whether they're answered at all. Luckily we have our `answer` field for each task already so we can use this. I also added selectTask in the onclick of each of the overview buttons to enable navigation back and forth.

```js
    var currentTask = 0;
    var tasks = [
      {
        statement:"Food and water is essential to surviving",
        description: "Consuming edibles and liquids is a crucial part of human survival.",
        correctAnswer: true,
        answer:null
      },
      {
        statement:"Asking questions on SA is stupid",
        description: "Despite what some may think, asking question on stack overflow doesn't make you a bad programmer",
        correctAnswer: false,
        answer:null
      },
      {
        statement:"Computer science is fun!",
        description: "Enough said.",
        correctAnswer: true,
        answer:null
      }
    ]

    function selectTask(id){
      if(id < 0 || id >= tasks.length) return; //Invalid ID entered.
      
      currentTask = id;
      
      document.getElementById("statement").innerText = tasks[currentTask].statement
      document.getElementById("description").innerText = tasks[currentTask].description      
    }
    
    function answer(value){
      tasks[currentTask].answer = value;
      console.log(value, currentTask)
      for(var task in tasks){
        if(tasks[task].answer === null){ /* do nothing*/}        
        else if(tasks[task].answer === tasks[task].correctAnswer)
          document.getElementById("task"+task).style.backgroundColor = "green"   
        else if(tasks[task].answer !== tasks[task].correctAnswer)
          document.getElementById("task"+task).style.backgroundColor = "red"   
      }
      
      if(currentTask < tasks.length-1){
        selectTask(currentTask+1)
      }
      
    }
    
    selectTask(0);
```

```html
<div>
<p id="statement"></p>
<p id="description"></p>
<button onclick="javascript:answer(true)">True</button>
<button onclick="javascript:answer(false)">False</button>

<div id="overview">
  <button id="task0" onclick="javascript:selectTask(0)">1</button>
  <button id="task1" onclick="javascript:selectTask(1)">2</button>
  <button id="task2" onclick="javascript:selectTask(2)">3</button>
</div>
</div>
```